# Expandable table interactive pdf

Tags: html, pdf, outlook, interactive, livecycle

I have a task to complete at work that I already completed once. The issue is Outlook and HTML templates. I created a large table that will be used as a pricing table for our customers but the issue is people don't know how to use html even when I dummy proof it with step by step instructions. I have attached the exact layout I need to produce to get some help with advice on what solution will be best for me to use. I have proposed the LiveCycle Designer by Adobe but I feel I am getting a snobby response from even suggesting this. PLEASE HELP! I have don't this 4 times using Acrobat Pro and the client hates it. I also redid it as an HTML template with Outlook specific code so it doesn't get mangled if it is forwarded to others.

Ok I need a reputation of 10 to post a picture so I will describe it the best I can. Let me know if I can send the image to anyone willing to help?

The table has an image header then Title and report date with a input text field next to it. Under this begins the table is has 12 columns and 29 rows. Each cell needs to be expandable in case the clients types in more characters and the form expands to show all the text in each cell. I would like everything to adjust to this.

I told them to use a Excel document but they said no. Then I suggested to just have each cell be larger so there is no need to have them be expandable. They shot that down as well due to the look of it. I really don't think I can pull this off without Adobe's Livecycle Designer.

Comment: Do they want an *interactive* PDF document that they can change by filling out fields that automatically resize? In that case, their only option is offering them a pure, dynamic XFA form (that's the kind of form you create when using Adobe LiveCycle Designer). Whoever doesn't agree is just ignorant. If they want a template that allows you to create *static* PDFs that are no longer interactive, then there are many options. However, if the PDF needs to remain dynamic, then you are right and they are wrong: you can't pull this off without Adobe LiveCycle Designer.

Comment: Ughhh I really hope I get the job in IT this marketing crap is just frustrating when the group knows nothing about technology and keep looking at me like I am speaking a non existent language. So there is more now that I just had another meeting regarding this project.

The scope is now that person A who edits this will send it to person B, Person B will also need to do small edits but then when person B sends it needs to locked down from editing capability. This can still only be achieved with Adobe Livecycle correct? Thank you very much for your advice on this Bruno!)

Comment: *small edits* - what are *small edits*? Probably PDF is not the right format after all. Concerning documents *locked down from editing capability*: this can beer achieved using digital PDF signatures. But that might be yet another topic your group does not accept.

Comment: yeah the pdf will need to go through 2 rounds of edits. The 2nd person would then lock it down and send it off to the client. Do you think that is achievable for Livecycle designer?